# Aggregating events in event-driven system

Tags: event-programming, stream-processing

Lets say there are two services. One generates event `A` and the other event `B`.
We need to build a new service that implements the function `C = func(A, B)` , which produces the result `C`.

But as `A` and `B` are asynchronous events, they may reach (and invoke) the new service separately. 
Depending on what is required, it may be apt for the new service to:

1. either wait for both events,
2. or implement different variations of the function: `C = func(A,C')` or `C = func(B,C')`  where `C'` is the previous state of `C` (assuming that it is even possible to build that function)
3. or query back to retrieve the complimentary event, e.g. if `A` invoked the service, then query for `B`.

Question:

Lets say the requirement is that we update the state of `C` ASAP, and `A` and `B` have a significant time gap in occurrence - that rules out option #1.

Additionally assume it is hard/impossible to build different variations of the function (#2).

That leaves us with option #3, which probably has drawbacks because it may be breaking the event driven paradigm (or maybe not, I am not sure).

How should we solve this problem? I expected this to be a common problem with a recommended pattern, but I could not find it.
Any suggestions or pointers on where I could find the answer, or if the question is wrong, how should I look at it?

Answer (score 4):

Whether it breaks the event-driven paradigm should not be your primary concern. The question is if this solves your business problem.

There are a number of questions that need to be answered:

- If `A` and `B` are events, it doesn't really make sense to query them. But I believe you mean they represent some state, and an event is raised when the state changes.
- Will querying `service B` yield a different result than simply taking the latest received event? In other words, could you simply call `func(A, B')` where `B'` comes from a cache? What do you do if the cache is empty? And do you need to invalidate it at some point?
- A query will cause the client of `service C` to block until `service B` responds. Will that be a problem? What if `service B` is unreachable?
- What happens if you receive a new `A` or `B` event while you are querying?

These are general problems of asynchronous systems and finding the right trade-offs is very specific to the requirements of your particular application.

Fundamentally, you just can't guarantee to get the most up-to-date state if your state is distributed. That means you either deal with temporary discrepancies (read up on 'eventual consistency') or you find a way to make the relevant parts synchronous (giving up the advantages of the asynchronous approach).

Comment: thanks, yes i did assume 'they represent some state, and an event is raised when the state changes', but again that assumption is not really inherent to this problem. 

I also think this problem is related to event-driven ETL, https://www.confluent.io/blog/changing-face-etl but a lot of blogs do not talk about this scenario, where data enrichment or data transformation is from other events.

like you said, i have to weight in trade-offs for my specific problem, but I like the idea service `C` caches only latest `A` or `B`, and deal with empty cache.